# What is git pull now?

Tags: git, github

I've been using git for a year and this is the first time I ask myself what is git pull is doing.

This is how I stumbed a problem. I accidently commit something into my dev branch, but that's fine. I create a new branch the pushed my changes there. So I went back to dev branch and stashed all of my commit using :

`$ git reset --hard origin/master`

Then I want the latest dev branch I do git pull.

Hmm it says merge conflict? what I want is just the latest version of the remote dev, that is it, I assume I already stash everything and it will be fine? What's wrong?

Comment: What `git pull` does is to run `git fetch` first, then `git merge` second. If you know that the `fetch` step will bring in changes for which `rebase` is more suitable, you can instruct `git pull` to use `git rebase` for its second step. (But how do you know which is more suitable? The way to be sure is to run `git fetch` yourself and inspect the result. Then run `git merge` if that's correct, or `git rebase` if that's what you prefer. So `git pull` has little value.)

Comment: rebase is like stash? I just want a copy of the latest dev branch.

Comment: No, rebase copies commits (presumably and ideally *your* commits) so that the new copies occur after some other point in the commit graph. (Git draws heavily on graph theory: commits form a Directed Acyclic Graph, and it is this DAG that makes up "history".  Rebase copies some old history to some new place, with the copied history having the same *effect*, but upon a different *starting point*.) The point of using Git in the first place is this ability to combine *your* work with *someone else's* work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git fetch, which will update your branch from remote repo. Then you should use git merge. Git pull also do the same thing but it will forcefully merge remote changes in your branch which may give conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the merge conflict is because the `origin/master` branch has some commits that `origin/dev` does not. However, the reason likely won't change the solution. To fix this, instead of `git reset --hard origin/master`, you will need to run:

```
$ git fetch origin dev
$ git checkout dev
$ git reset --hard origin/dev
```

The first command will get any changes to `origin/dev` since you last pulled.

The second command is just to ensure that you are on the `dev` branch.

The third command will reset your local `dev` branch to look exactly like the remote `origin/dev` branch.